# rails environments mixup, development server uses production db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, environment

In the first few rails app I setup for small apps to learn I used

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:setup
```

and it created the (mysql) tables on myapp_production

But this time I am not able to populate development or test DB. It just writes to production, also the app running on the Mongrel server writes to production DB but says it'S development environment on startup:

```
$ rails server
WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.3.6) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1
WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.9 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

I don't use rvm here (tried on another box and guess I like it)

I am not sure how to troubeshoot this. And there is no error message.

Comment: have you tried running `rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=development`?

Comment: Whats the config for dev environment in the database.yml?

Answer (score 0):

You use old Rails version. mysql2 gem as of 0.3.0 do not support rails 3.0 and earlier. So you need either update rails to 3.1.x or higher or use gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2.7" in your Gemfile. See [mysql2 gem page](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2), search for "3.0" in your browser.

Maybe that's the reason.